# Apache POI org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException for shiftrows function call.

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read and write Excel files for both xls and xlsx formats.

If the code processes folloiwng line for a file written by POI/my code , it doesn't throw an exception but in case of a file written from Excel by user, I get

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT' does not exist in the current workbook.
```

The Exception is fired at:

```
postWB.getSheet(postSheet.getSheetName()).shiftRows(i, postSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(), 1);
```

As it turns out from some of the questions here, it can be of jar compatibilities or due to [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56502). I have changed all jars for latest poi library and dependencies.

Any workaround to shiftrows without finding this exception.

Comment: May be somewhere else code is breaking, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168418/conditional-formatting-using-in-excel-using-apache-poi

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you try upgrading?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr it wasn't latest and I replaced with latest libs as well. Problem stays as it is.

Comment: Any solution for this? we are stucked with the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Had to write our own.

Comment: I am running into this same exception org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT' does not exist in the current workbook.
You say "write our own". Own what? I'm hoping to get a solution that doesn't require rewriting the entire workbook.